# Jquery Modal Popup dialog not loading content

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I want to show a modal popup which will contain list of string

I tried this

in `Jquery`

```
$("#modalFilterDiv").load("<div><p>This is html generated from Jquery</p><ul><li>"+loopChartID+"</li></ul></div>").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hieght: 450,
        width: 800,
        dialogClass: 'FilterSelectedList',
        modal: true

    }).dialog("open");
```

in `Index.cshtml`

```
<div id="modalFilterDiv" title="Select Controls To Filter">
</div>
```

I am calling this on one of the button click. it is showing blank modal popup without any data

> without p tag and li tag

I want to load the data from load function which will return one item right now.
When I debug this I am able to see value in loopChartID but it is not showing on modal popup.

```
<div><p>Heading for List goes here</p><ul><li>"+loopChartID+"</li></ul></div>"
```

Please help me understand this and to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$.fn.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) loads data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element. Where as you need to set the HTML content so instead of [`$.fn.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) use [`$.fn.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$("#modalFilterDiv")
    .html("<div><p>This is html generated from Jquery</p><ul><li>"+loopChartID+"</li></ul></div>")
    .dialog({
    });
```

---

Use loop to generate HTML

```
var ul = $('<ul />');
for(var i =0;i <10; i++){
    ul.append($('<li />', { text : i }));
}

var div = $('<div />')
            .html('<p>This is html generated from Jquery</p>')
            .append(ul);

$("#modalFilterDiv")
    .html(div)
    .dialog({
    });
```

```js
$(function() {
  var ul = $('<ul />');
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ul.append($('<li />', {
      text: i
    }));
  }

  var div = $('<div />')
    .html('<p>This is html generated from Jquery</p>')
    .append(ul);

  $("#modalFilterDiv")
    .html(div);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modalFilterDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It work like a charm. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: can I use for loop inside that `html()`

Comment: @AmeyDeshpande, What exactly you need?

Comment: `loopChartID` are mulitple entries. Like Chart1, Chart2, Chart3, Chart4 so I want to show list of these elements. Can I do that using this `$.html()`

Comment: `li` tag I want to repeat till looChartID length and add that number of `li` in list...

Comment: Thanks a lot. it was very helpful